# Does the singer Dua Lipa have a sister?

Tags: singers

The singer Dua Lipa appears with a lookalike in a clip ([*IDGAF*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mgfe5tIwOj0)).

Is it her sister or is it really a montage? I thought it was very real.

Comment: Could you specify which extra do you consider as a lookalike? Maybe a screenshot would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dua_Lipa) she does have a sister:

> *Lipa has two younger siblings, **a sister named Rina** and a brother named Gjin.*

Answer (score 0):

She has a sister name Gjin Lipa.
https://www.instagram.com/gjinlipa/?hl=en

Comment: According to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dua_Lipa) Gjin is her brother, but she has a sister called Rina